# Continuous dependence of SDE on the driving process

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose on some compact time interval $[0,T]$ I have an SDE with sufficiently nice coefficients:
$$
dX_t = \sigma(X_t) dB_t + \mu(X_t) dt
$$
Is there any general statement that shows some form of pathwise quantitatively continuous dependence of the solution $X_t$ on $B_t$? What I mean would e.g. be a statement of the form:
$$
\sup_{t \in [0,T]}\vert X_t \vert \leq C(T) \sup_{t \in [0,T]}\vert B_t \vert
$$
, holding trajectory by trajectory, or some variant thereof?

I'm phrasing the question in general, but the SDE of interest comes from the unitary Brownian motion on the unitary group.

Comment: Your last inequality, did you mean
$$
\sup_{t \in [0,\color{red}{T}]}\vert X_t \vert \leq C(T) \sup_{t \in [0,\color{red}{T}]}\vert B_t \vert
$$
And this statement is just an illustration, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed, and yes, this is just an illustration of what kind of statement I'm hoping for.

Comment: So, I think my answer is what you are looking for. Indeed, $C(T) = \sigma$ and we need an additional term $\mu T$.  Or perhaps you are looking for other things?

Answer (score 0):

$$X_t = \mu t+\sigma W_t \iff |X_t-\mu t|=\sigma |B_t|$$
Because
$$|X_t| = |(X_t-\mu t)+\mu t| \le |X_t-\mu t|+ |\mu| t$$
We deduce
$$|X_t| \le |\mu| t + \sigma |B_t|$$
$$\Longrightarrow \color{red}{ \sup_{t \in [0,T]}\vert X_t \vert  \le |\mu| T+ \sigma \cdot \sup_{t \in [0,T]}\vert B_t \vert} \tag{1}$$
The inequality $(1)$ is tight as the equality can occur. Indeed, if the trajectory $(B_t(\omega))_{t\in[0,T]}$ correspond to the event $\omega$ satisfy $B_t(\omega)=0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall t\in[0,T]$, then the equality of $(1)$ holds.

Comment: I think OP may have unclear notation; their wording seems to imply that the coefficient they consider are functions of $t$ and $X$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was unclear. fixed.